# podman container ip address should remain same with disconnect and connect

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, ip, container

Assume podman network `net1` and container `cont1`.
I connect podman network to a container during creation with `--net net1`. Also use `podman network disconnect/connect net1 cont1` commands to dis-and-connect the virtual nic `net1`.
The ip address inside container increments by 1 each time I disconnect and connect the nic `net1`.

What I tried but did not help to achieve what I need:

```
podman network rm net1
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
nmcli nm enable false
sleep 5
nmcli nm enable true 
killall NetworkManager && sudo NetworkManager
podman network create net1
```

For these tries I assumed perhaps the NetworkManager remembers previous ip addresses and hence assigns next address with dhcp on podman nic `net1`.
I tried above block of code between `podman network disconnect` and `podman network connect`, and also between (symbolic commands):`podman stop and remove cont1` and `podman create cont1 with --net net1`. None of these steps helped.

If ip address inside `cont1` once is `10.89.0.2`, next time (after dis-/-connect net1 to cont1 OR after remove cont1 + create cont1 + connect cont1 to net1) would be `10.89.0.3`. I need it to stay at `10.89.0.2`.

System specs:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

```
podman version 3.4.2
```

I'm using `sudo` with all these commands including for the `podman`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to assign the same IP for your container every time. In simple words, you want your container with static IP.

Then you have to start your container with the parameter

Creating my own network

```bash
podman network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/16 mydockernetwork
```

Starting a container with static IP `--ip` param

```bash
podman run --net mydockernetwork --ip 172.18.0.4 -it --name ubuntu_static_ip ubuntu
```

Lets find out the IP Address

```
[bob@centos-host ~]$ podman inspect c88945483ee4 | grep -i IPAddress
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.4",
```

Stopping the container

```
[bob@centos-host ~]$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND         CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS       NAMES
c88945483ee4  docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest  sh -c sleep 1d  About a minute ago  Up About a minute ago              ubuntu_static_ip2
[bob@centos-host ~]$ podman stop c88945483ee4
c88945483ee4
[bob@centos-host ~]$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED     STATUS      PORTS       NAMES
```

Now start again

```
[bob@centos-host ~]$ podman start c88945483ee4
c88945483ee4
[bob@centos-host ~]$ podman inspect c88945483ee4 | grep -i IPAddress
            "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.4",
[bob@centos-host ~]$
```

As you can see IP Address didn't change.
Hope it helps.

Ref: http://thelinuxmen.blogspot.com/2021/08/docker-networking-basisc-configure.html for more information.